Typing parameters using built-in functions in python
Can I use built-in functions to type parameters in my functions?
function 1
def foo_foo(a=int(), b=int()):return a + b

I understand that we can use hints for typing:
function 2
def foo_foo(a: int, b: int):return a + b

I wonder whether function 1 is somehow different from function 2. The results are the same.
I've tried both. They work without any issues.

In function_1, you are not doing any typing. You are setting default values.

Great. Thank you for being very explicit about that. What is the difference in behavior between function 1 and function 2?

The first one can be called without any arguments: foo_foo() and foo_foo(0, 0) are equivalent. For the second one, foo_foo() is a type error, as neither argument is optional.

There is no type-hinting going on in your first function. You are supplying default arguments (int() == 0) for both parameters, which means you do not need to provide arguments when you call the function. But neither argument necessarily needs to be a int, either.
>>> def f(x=int(), y=int()): return x + y
...
>>> f()
0
>>> f(3)
3
>>> f(3, 5)
8
>> f("foo", "bar")
'foobar'

With type hints, there are no default values; every argument is required. The type hints don't have any effect at runtime, but programs like mypy can be used to ensure you code does not try to pass non-int arguments at runtime.
$ cat tmp.py
def f(x: int, y: int): return x +  y
$ python3 -i tmp.py
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y'
>>> f(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
>>> f(3, 5)
8
>>> f("foo", "bar")
'foobar'
>>> exit()

$ cat tmp2.py
def f(x: int, y: int): return x +  y

print(f("foo", "bar"))
$ mypy tmp2.py
tmp.py:3: error: Argument 1 to "f" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"  [arg-type]
tmp.py:3: error: Argument 2 to "f" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"  [arg-type]
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
$ python3 tmp2.py
foobar


Okay, thank you. When I use either of these functions supplied with parameters different than int, I get warnings that the type is wrong: expected int got float or str instead. I thought that some sort of typing was going on anyway, since the behavior of IDE is identical in both cases.
